# Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted. (flamingo)

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools

Currently I installed Android Studio Flamingo it is the latest version.
I went through all the process to install it, but I am getting an error

"Your Android SDK is missing, out of date or corrupted"

I looked solution for this problem on YouTube and on StackOverflow but all in vain. I reinstalled android studio again and again.

After doing a more researh I came to know that we need to go the Skd folder, but that particular folder is not present in my files. I can only see the local foder but the android folder is not present in there.

I am attaching some screen shots of the same. PLEASE HELP ME!!
[The main problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2ROm.png)

[[The path where the sdk is supposed to be but is not.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PDM8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj5cO.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIYFZ.png)
Please Help I am not getting this error.